# how do I control order of promoted pages?

Tags: nodes

I have a bunch of pages I have promoted to the front page and I'm wondering how I can control the order the items appear in? This is in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tutorial at [Custom re-ordered front page teasers](http://www.absolutecross.com/tutorials/drupal/custom-re-ordered-front-page-teasers). It uses the pre-packaged view `Front page` that comes with Views, as well as the [Nodequeue](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodequeue) module to re-order the teasers.

> The Nodequeue module allows users to collect nodes in an arbitrarily
>   ordered list. The order in the list can be used for a any purpose

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution is the [draggable views](https://www.drupal.org/project/draggableviews) module.

You can set up a view of promoted content ordered by the draggable views weight and then add another display to the view for reordering.

There is more detailed information on how to set this up on the draggable views [documentation page](https://www.drupal.org/node/283498).

With this you get a little contextual link on your view that will take you to the reordering page, where you can drag and drop your list of content to reorder, than save that order.

It's quite a nice user experience for reordering lists.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by just changing the **Authored on** date & time. Works very well!

Comment: Then you don't have an accurate "authored on" date.

Comment: @rooby That is correct but it works for me to re-order the "promoted on fronpage" items - and it may also for other people...